# extract formatted text from pdf to html

Tags: java, html, pdf

I needed to covert PDF documents into HTML. where i can achieve below.

1-Extract the text from the PDF.

2-extract the images

3-Retain the formatting in the newly converted HTML page same as that of PDF page.

4-To embed the images into the newly converted HTML page in the appropriate places as that of PDF.

5- Applying color scheme to HTML page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) *may* be able to do this.

Comment: iText just generate the plain text from pdf, it does not maintain the format.

Answer (score 0):

To extract images from PDF
 [Image Extraction](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=284)
To extract text from PDF
[Text Extraction](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=482)

All the other things you are seeking answers for are possible using any web-application setup.,

Comment: iText does but it does not maintain the format, it just convert the pain text.